# Python3: overflow but I dont even have values assigned yet

Tags: python-3.x, overflow

I have this so far but I get teh overflow error seen below verbatim. It does not seem to like the prod = num_1 + num_ 2 line as that is what is triggering the error.

```
def p_mult(num_1, num_2):
    prod = 0
    while num_2 != 0:
        if (num_1%2 != 0): # is odd?
            num_1 = (num_1-1) / 2
            num_2 = (2 * num_2) + num_2
            prod = num_1 * num_2

        elif (num_1%2 == 0): # is even?
           num_1 = num_1 / 2
           num_2 = 2 * num_2
           prod = num_1 * num_2

    return prod
```

And it states in the interpreter when I try my module: ...p_mult(3, 38)

> OverflowError: int too large to convert to float

I am supposed to be designing a peasant multiplication function but I have to perform a check on the value of `num_1` to see if it is even or odd, if even,

`num_1 = num_1/2 while num_2 = 2 * num_2` 
Then perform the multiplication, and

`if num_1 odd: num_1 = (num_1 -1)/2 and num_2 = (2 * num_2) + num_2`, then perform the multiplication.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After some amount of testing, I believe I have determined the issue. Unfortunately, I didn't realize before I wrote the testing code, but the problem is that **num_2 doesn't go to zero, num_1 does**. And, since your while loop only checks on num_2, num_1 just continues at zero while num_2 gets infinitely large until it can no longer be multiplied.

Here is what I used to test this, for future reference:

```
class Tester:

    def get_num_1(self):
        return self._num_1

    def set_num_1(self, value):
        print("num_1", value)
        self._num_1 = value

    def get_num_2(self):
        return self._num_2

    def set_num_2(self, value):
        print("num_2", value)
        self._num_2 = value

    num_1 = property(get_num_1, set_num_1)
    num_2 = property(get_num_2, set_num_2)

    def p_mult(self):

        prod = 0
        while self.num_2 != 0:
            if (self.num_1%2 != 0): # is odd?
                self.num_1 = (self.num_1-1) / 2
                self.num_2 = (2 * self.num_2) + self.num_2
                prod = self.num_1 * self.num_2

            elif (self.num_1%2 == 0): # is even?
               self.num_1 = self.num_1 / 2
               self.num_2 = 2 * self.num_2
               prod = self.num_1 * self.num_2

        return prod

t = Tester()
t.num_1 = 5
t.num_2 = 6
t.p_mult()
```